# ERROR:'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: android, keytool

When I use the command:

```
C:\>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey 
            -keystore .android\debug.keystore 
            -storepass android -keypass android
```

I get this error:

> 'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I'm not able to get the certificate fingerprint(MD5) on my computer.

I have ensured that the keystore file is present in the appropriate location.

Any help?

Comment: For Flutter: I have written an answer on a different SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66739456/12349734)

Comment: The answers here are dominantly for Windows, but troubleshooting your `PATH` is a common FAQ; it's not hard to find answers for Linux etc once you understand what the problem is. Basically, if you have not installed `keytool`, install it; then, if the directory where it is installed is not on your `PATH`, add it there.

Answer (score 280, accepted):

Check that the directory the keytool executable is in is on your `%PATH%` environment variable.

For example, on my Windows 7 machine, it is in 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin`, and my `%PATH%` variable looks like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\` (and many other entries)

Comment: i entered this                                               C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore .android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android.                                                 the error i got is keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: .android\debug
.keystore

Comment: If you do that, it's going to be looking for the keystore in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\.android\debug.keystore` which is almost certainly not the correct path.  You need to give it the correct full path to your keystore.

Comment: the keystore file is here C:\Documents and Settings\Shalini\.android>                                         so when i enter                                             C:\Documents and Settings\Shalini\.android>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore .android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android .                                                  i get this same error 'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Try `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Documents and Settings\Shalini\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android`

Comment: ok i entered this C:\Documents and Settings\Shalini\.android> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21
\bin\keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Documents and Settings\Shalini\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android .                                                          the error is
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: i also tried this :    C:\>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -
keystore C:\Documents and Settings\Shalini\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android  . and the error was   'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Try putting quotes around the paths in case the spaces in the directory names is confusing things.  Or try copying your keystore file into the java bin directory and calling keystool from that directory, not using paths at all.

Comment: i copied the keystore file into the java bin and then entered C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore bin\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android  .and the error is                                                keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: bin\debug.keys
tore

Comment: If you are in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin` directory, calling `bin\debug.keystore` looks for a keystore file in the directory `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\bin\debug.keystore` which does not exist.  Leave the bin\ out.

Comment: do you place this in the user variables or in the system variables

Answer (score 144):

This worked for me !! :

Go to this path or where ever you have your keytool.exe file

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
```

Hold `shift` and right click -> then press `Open command window here`

terminal will pop up, paste this in:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\"Your-User-Name(no quotes)"\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

gives you both MD5 and SHA1

Comment: This works but @Amt87 's answer will make sure you have keytool available in any directory without having to first cd to the directory where keytool is located (windows only).

in OS X (Mac), edit your .profile and be sure to include :$PATH at the end or you will have no commands. (see http://architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/#.VAfw_PldXuw)

Comment: For me: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281\jre\bin

Comment: As an addition to whoever else having my problem, I use IntelliJ's own JDK that comes with the IDE. Running the command inside the proper directory and it having keytool.exe in it still returned that keytool was not found on CMD or PowerShell. But it worked when run from the IDE's terminal.

Answer (score 88):

Found it.

GO TO:

```
my computer->rightClick->properties->Advanced system settings->environment variables->find path in system variables->dbl click-> paste the "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin"->OK
```

GO TO:

```
cmd -> keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\meee\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

Answer (score 34):

1. Go to My computer -> right click -> system properties -> environmental variables -> Path ->
   add you jdk/bin to this path

   ```
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin
   ```

*if this not work then

2. In cmd set the path by using the below command

   ```
   set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin
   ```

now the path is set now you can use the keytool

Comment: Thanks, in Windows 10 I tried the first solution and for some reasons didn't work. The 2nd one works great.

Comment: Thanks. The second option worked for me on Windows 10 x64

Answer (score 18):

`keytool` ships with Android Studio as part of the JRE needed to run Android Studio.

On Windows its: `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool.exe`

On Mac its: `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/keytool`

Add it to your environment variables then run the keytool command again.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! As for 2022, totally works!

Comment: In my case, I added the "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool.exe"as a path variable. And tried out. But it didn't work quite as expected inspite the restart I did. Though "cd"ing via cmd to  C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\ and ensure the file keytool.exe exists. I was able to work the following cmd   "keytool -genkey -v -keystore %userprofile%\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload" as mentioned in https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#create-an-upload-keystore

Answer (score 13):

So if you have the following structure now:

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\
                                keytool.exe
                                debug.keystore
```

then execute:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: I have jdk-13 ..it has no jre file .How can I solve this

Comment: Navigate to `C:\Softwares\jdk1.8.0_261\jre\bin` folder.

Answer (score 11):

On windows 8, go to C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin and in the address bar, type "cmd" without the quotes. This will launch the terminal. Then type in string as describe [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key).

Answer (score 10):

**This is due to path for keytool.exe not set.**

Open command prompt in your windows machine, go to where you would like to run keytool cmd and then set path where `keytool.exe` present

Step 1 : Open cmd promt and run

```
cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk<your jdk version>\jre\lib\security
```

Step 2 : Run below cmd to set path using

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk<your jdk version>\bin
```

Step 3 : Run keytool cmd, now it will be able to recognize

```
keytool -list -alias <rest of the arguments>
```

Answer (score 7):

if you want to run keytool from any location of terminal

example: C:>keytool

you need to add the system variables

for Windows:

```
1) create:
JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45

2) add to Path
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
```

Answer (score 7):

all you can do is to navigate to your jre destination in your computer via command line and then once you reach bin, you type the keytool command and it would work.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin>
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore"%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android



Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: 23 Feb, 2014
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Serial number: 479d4fe7
Valid from: Sun Feb 23 06:19:02 IST 2014 until: Tue Feb 16 06:19:02 IST 2044
Certificate fingerprints:
MD5:  DB:6A:8E:48:22:5B:37:73:B1:91:EF:43:3F:26:F0:EC
SHA1: B4:6B:2E:5F:5A:30:C5:E4:E7:12:BB:F0:74:FC:2B:43:64:3A:FC:15
SHA256: CB:59:F3:20:7D:5B:87:99:6C:0D:32:79:79:CF:4E:8C:16:C2:37:81:7B:
B0:AF:D2:EC:3C:11:21:53:58:62:F6
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Version: 3
Extensions:
#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: FA 96 17 9E 94 73 C3 42   F0 4B 55 5B C7 5B EE BB  .....s.B.KU[.[..
0010: C3 E5 D3 61                                        ...a
]
]
```

Comment: Which one of these is key hash and which one is Development Key Hashes and which one is Release Key Hashes?

Answer (score 7):

Easy, just find the location where keytool executable is, normally is in `java/jre(Version)/bin` forexample in my computer is in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin`. all you have to do is **go to environment variables**, **click PATH to make it active, then click edit, then add complete path where your keytool is**, for me i will add `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin` this will allow you to execute keytool commands without going to the directory where keytool is installed.

Answer (score 6):

I suffered alot trying to find a solution to it and finally I found the solution by first setting the **jre** path to system variables by navigating to::

```
control panel > System and Security > System > Advanced system settings
```

Under System variables click on new

```
Variable name: KEY_PATH
Variable value: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin
```

Where Variable value should be the path to your JDK's bin folder.

Then open command prompt and Change directory to the same JDK's bin folder like this

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin
```

then copy and paste the code below in cmd

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\user\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure JAVA_HOME is set and the path in environment variables reflects the bin directory of JAVA_HOME.
Basically, the PATH should be able to find the keytools.exe file in your jdk location.

Answer (score 3):

This means, that your shell couldn't find the tool on your harddisk.

A)

- Change the working directory to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\`
- Execute `keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey keystore <full directory name make sure that you use enclosing in quotes> -storepass android -keypass android`

B)

- Add `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\` to your `PATH` variable

Answer (score 2):

In my case problem was in using PowerShell instead of CMD :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use **flutter** and have downloaded [openssl-for-windows](https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads):

- Open **Command Prompt**
- Type `flutter doctor -v`
- Under **Android toolchain** you will see `Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\jre\bin\java`
- Now copy the line of code and do `cd C:\Program Files\Android\jre\bin`
- Type `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Username\.android\debug.keystore" | "Location to openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "Location to openssl.exe" base64`

(Double quotes are necessary)

- Enter keystore password:  **android** (default password)

This will give you **Key Hash**.

Now,

if you are trying to get your **SHA fingerprint**, this is the *easiest way* to get it -->

Step 1: Open terminal in your project directory

Step 2: cd android

Step 3: Run ".\gradlew signingReport"

Done!

Answer (score 2):

i am using gui tool ,Must try Who don't want to use keystore command line

it is GUI tool for create **keystore.jks** and export *pem* file and lot

https://keystore-explorer.org/downloads.html

Answer (score 1):

Give:

```
keytool -list -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

Also in your line there is a space in keystore. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

I know there are already several answers but none of them worked for me, so i am posting one that worked for me, may be helpful for someone.

First of all directory to keytool.exe must be on path

and if instead of directory being on path it is giving error then Try starting command line as a normal user instead of as a administrator or changing the directory to home directory

Answer (score 1):

Open "Environment Variables" (you can get to it from your start menu search in Win10)
double check the path that the jdk is in, to make sure it exists.
For me, it said "...jdk1.8/bin"
But when I copied that into Windows Explorer or command prompt, it said that it didn't exist.
I checked where it should have been, and it said "jdk1.8.0_77"

A simple rename of the setting in Android Studio and keytool was working!

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution of error is that you first need to change the folder directory in command prompt. By default in command prompt or in terminal(Inside Android studio in the bottom)tab
the path is set to 
C:\Users#Name of your PC that you selected\AndroidStudioProjects#app name\flutter_app>
**Change accordingly:-**
C:\Users#Name of your PC that you selected\AndroidStudioProjects#app name\flutter_app>cd\

## type **cd** (#after flutter_app>), type only cd\ not comma's

## then type cd **Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251\bin** (#remember to check the file name of jre properly)

## now type **keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android** (without anyspace type the command).

[screenshot of the codes to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEFDa.png)

Comment: I am a beginner flutter developer struggling to finish up my app. I kept getting this error, not until i saw this answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to C:->Program Files->Java->jdk->bin. Here,keytool.exe file resides.
   2.Copy the path till bin.
   3.Go to: Control Panel\System and Security\System
   4.Click Advanced System Setting
   5.Click Environment Variables
   6.Under System Variables(bottom half): Double click on Variable: Path
   B. Add the path: (Click New then add)
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin
   (your path)
   8.VERIFY:
   Open command prompt & enter "Keytool"
   It should show keytool details & no error mssg.

Answer (score 1):

add `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin` this into Environment Variables.
refer to [this](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/keytool-command-not-found-how-to-fix-windows-macos/) website.

Answer (score 1):

That simply means the keytool keyword is not installed in your system
visit : [visit here](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/keytool-command-not-found-how-to-fix-windows-macos/) and download [java JDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk17-windows) first.

Then set the java JDK in your environmental variable.

Answer (score 0):

The Works for fine

Go to Path

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Developer\.android\debug.keystore"
```

Then enter Ketsore Password and job done!!

Answer (score 0):

Open Command prompt
type this..

"c:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\keytool.exe" -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\EIS.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android

Then Hit Enter MD5 and SHA1  key will get

Answer (score 0):

For windows 10 you need to path `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin`

restart command and open

Answer (score 0):

Locate where your keytool.exe inside java installation folder

mine is 
`C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin` open cmd anywhere and run

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin;
```

change the path to the path you located your keytool.exe

Answer (score 0):

My case is, it doesn't work wherever I call it, no matter I path the file or not, if I open it with powershell.

but it works if I open it with cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Just search on the following path :
C:\  → Program Files → Java → jre1.xxx  → bin
be sure this bin folder includes this keytool.exe

Then open the command prompt.

then type : (cd means change directory)
cd C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231\bin

Then type the command, and press enter

Answer (score 0):

The keytool command might not be in your path—it’s part of Java, which is installed as part of Android Studio. For the concrete path, run flutter doctor -v and locate the path printed after ‘Java binary at:’. Then use that fully qualified path replacing java (at the end) with keytool. If your path includes space-separated names, such as Program Files, use platform-appropriate notation for the names. For example, on Mac/Linux use Program\ Files, and on Windows use "Program Files".

Answer (score 0):

open Advanced system settings --> open environment variable --> in system variable double click on "Path" --> copy your jdk path from C , should be like this "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin" and paste it after click on New --> click ok then restart android studio , this should fix the problem

Answer (score -1):

You may be opening **Terminal**, above command should be run from **Command Prompt** as an **Administrator**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

1. Open where your KEYTOOL.EXE in yourJAVA file such as
   e.g C:\Program Files\Java\bin\keytool.exe.
2. HOLD SHIFT and Right Click on the BIN Folder where your keytool.exe is located
   and click open CMD or RUN Command from here.
3. This opens cmd. then type in

keytool -exportcert -alias NAME OF YOUR KEYSTORE -keystore PATH OF KEYSTORE.jks" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64

4. Password Prompt, enter android and BOOOOOOOM...You have your Key.