# Setting java home for project

Tags: java

In windows 7 CMD, I want to execute the command `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA`. This command is not the main thing.

So, for this I created `JAVA_HOME` system variable with value `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10`. Then, I created a user variable `PATH` = `%JAVA_HOME%`\bin. I did NOT
restart my computer. I also tried one more thing - delete user variable `PATH` and then 
put `;%java_home%\bin` inside an already existing system variable called `Path`.

Now, when I execute the cmd command, I get an error - `the system cannot find the path specified`. I use eclipse and stopped using javac, cmd etc. a long time ago. How do I make this work ?

Comment: Reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7

Comment: Close the command prompt and start it again. That change in system variable will not reflect till next start of the command prompt.

Comment: Simply run `path` in command prompt to show its actual value.

Comment: Try doing `echo %PATH%` ans see if `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` shows up. If it does not then env variable is not properly set. So check the %PATH% variable again. You should use `;` and then add you new path to the variable. If this is good restart the cmd and try. And before trying keytool you can simply type `java` and check or `java -version`.

Comment: are trying to do `cd %JAVA_HOME%`? than output `the system cannot find the path specified` is fine.Try `echo %Path%`

Comment: @AniketThakur - Okay. I just restarted my system and did your command. I cd-ed into jdk directory. Please put this as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @AniketThakur - Only problem is that the main cmd command gives me an error - `C:\Program is not recognized as an internal of external command`

Comment: Solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211919/errorkeytool-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing `echo %PATH%` and see if `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` shows up. If it does not then env variable is not properly set. So check the %PATH% variable again. You should use `;` and then add you new path to the variable. If this is good restart the cmd and try. And before trying keytool you can simply type `java` and check or `java -version`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Aniket...I like you.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, restart your window$ system to be safe. Secondly, you need to check if the jdk folder in your variable is set correctly. Run cmd as admin and type `cd %JAVA_HOME%`. If that gets you into 
the jdk directory, then your settings work.

Now, the main cmd still won't work because your jdk folder path has spaces - Program Files...So, put any path inside double quotes to fix that. Now, run your cmd as follows -

`"%JAVA_HOME%\bin"keytool....blah...blah`

Great success !

Comment: Was just taking the screenshot for this :)