# 'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: android

When I write this command in the terminal `keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -alias XXXXXXXX`

I get the message:

```
'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

What can I do?

Comment: have you setted up the environment variables?

Comment: I was able to solve the problem but now it write to me:
keytool -list [OPTION]...

Lists entries in a keystore

Options:

 
 -storepass <arg>                keystore password
 -storetype <storetype>          keystore type
 -providername <providername>    provider name
 -providerclass <providerclass>  provider class name
 -providerarg <arg>              provider argument

Comment: Dear Ron, will you please mark my answer as correct if you manage to solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR:'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211919/errorkeytool-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-p)

Answer (score 9):

**Solution:** Add android jre bin folder to your path in environment variables.

***Instructions:***

1- Right click on "This PC" > right-click Properties > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables > select PATH then EDIT.

2- Add your jre bin folder path to environment variables, it should look like this:

"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin".

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me to solve same error.

Comment: I wonder why @Ron still didn't confirm this as the correct answer!