# Keytool Is Not Recognized As An Internal/External Command

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, keytool

Good day, I'm having a hard time getting my key. I followed some of the suggested answer in this link [ERROR: Keytool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211919/errorkeytool-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-p), but none of them work.

These are the steps that i made:

CMD-> **cd .android** (I changed directory) -> **dir** (show list in .android folder)

[image: cd . android]

After that I locate my keytool path directory and paste it in cmd

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\keytool"

[image: path directory]

**The problem is in this next step:** keytool -list -v keystore 
debug.keystore

It will produce error: keytool is not recognized as an internal/external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
keytool -list -v keystore debug.keystore
```

cd into `.android`

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\keytool" -list -v -keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass androiddebug.keystore
```

Generally (without cd-ing);

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\keytool" -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\username\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Or

If your aim is to generate a new key do;

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\keytool" -genkey -v -keystore mykey.keystore
```

You will find the key at `"C:\Users\username\mykey.keystore"`

Be sure to replace `username` above with your username on your computer

Comment: Many Thank you, I tried that without cd-ing and it works. If it is ok with you can you explain to me the mykey.keystore thing? I tried that and open the file, but there is no key.

Comment: "mykey.keystore" is just a name for the keystore file.

Comment: But if you are asking about the keystore, its purpose is to provide secure system level credential storage. In other words it stores keys used this to encrypt application secrets before saving it in the private storage folders. more info http://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) I've been somehow enlighten by these facts.