# -alias is not recognized as an internal or external command windows

Tags: android-studio

How can I fix this? I typed in the command prompt for Windows 10:

```
-alias androiddebugkey
```

And this is the result:

> -alias is not recognized as an internal or external command windows

Comment: What was the desired result?

Comment: I think you are looking for this solution
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211919/errorkeytool-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-p](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211919/errorkeytool-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-p)

Comment: I think you are looking for SHA1. This link helped me
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211919/errorkeytool-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-p](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211919/errorkeytool-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-p)

Answer (score 0):

you may need using [cmder](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder) which lets you add aliases just like linux.
and it only for `alias xxxxxx` but not `-alias xxxxx`

Answer (score 0):

I am using windows 10 and on command prompt, alias command is not working.

Now I have **tried -alias command on gitbash, and it's working**.