# I can't get 'create-rmi-keystore.bat' to run on windows, is there a solution to this?

Tags: windows, jmeter, keystore

I am new to Jmeter 5.1.1 however I am in the process of setting up a remote testing with it. 
One step I'm having trouble with is running 'create-rmi-keystore.bat' when I double click it nothing happens. I have tried to open it using the command line and get the following message.

'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
"Copy the generated rmi_keystore.jks to jmeter/bin folder or reference it in property 'server.rmi.ssl.keystore.file'"

I don't seem to have a rmi-keystore.jks . 
Has anyone managed to solve this issue?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211919/errorkeytool-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-p

Answer (score 0):

You don't have [`keytool` utility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html) in your Windows [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)), all you need to do is to ensure that it's there.

Solution using [Windows Command Prompt](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/chusedos.htm) would be:

```
set PATH="path\to\bin\folder\of\your\JDK\or\JRE\installation";%PATH%
```

[image]

---

In general if you don't need the secure RMI communication between JMeter master and slave machines (and 99% of people don't need this as it doesn't add any value and only creates overhead in terms of CPU and RAM) you can just disable this functionality by adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
```

References:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)

If you do this on JMeter master and all the slaves you will not have to worry about the RMI keystore, but I would still recommend having the `keytool` in the PATH otherwise you will not be able to use [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) for recording secure traffic.