# How do you install the keystore in flutter?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, keystore

I tried to install Keystore in flutter so, inside the terminal, I wrote:

```
(keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\USER_NAME\key.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key)
```

However, it said:

```
'key tool' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.
```

And it doesn't work. How can I fix it? Is there something I should add in the Environment variables? (I'm using Windows 10).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me say you a quick solution!
Better open the command prompt. Go to the folder where you have installed Java.
Eg: In my case, it is C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211\bin
Command Looks like this

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211\bin"
```

Now try to execute your previous key tool command.
If it works so, add the above path to your Environment Variables.

Further Reference: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#signing-the-app

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#signing-the-app):

> The keytool command might not be in your path—it’s part of Java, which
> is installed as part of Android Studio. For the concrete path, run
> `flutter doctor -v` and locate the path printed after 'Java binary at:'.
> Then use that fully qualified path replacing java (at the end) with
> keytool. If your path includes space-separated names, such as Program
> Files, use platform-appropriate notation for the names. For example,
> on Mac/Linux use `Program\ Files`, and on Windows use `Program Files".

---

For example, if I run `futter -v`:

```
...

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Mendel\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\Mendel\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
...
```

Locate where it says `"Java binary at"`  and replace the path `\java` with `keytool`, So if Java is installed at:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
```

`keytool` would be at:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool
```

---

So, for example, to get the debug certificate fingerprint I ran:

```
"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool" -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

Answer (score 0):

Here mate [click me!](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#signing-the-app)

Also you can find out more about exporting your app and making it ready for publishing there.