# Login Screen won't connect to Firebase Authentication

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am trying to connect `Firebase` to my Login Page in `Flutter`, but I cannot connect because of the following errors:

```
 Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.

Notifying id token listeners about user ( e3OIktY1XafU7ddf5yMgALiA69c2 ).
```

What does it mean and How can I fix this? Appreciate if someone can advise. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check your emulator/phone is connected to internet connection

Comment: How? It is using mobile data I guess because when I try searching in the browser, it is loading so I assume it is using its cellular data

Comment: when you try to search on browser. does it work or reply?

Comment: Yes it does really work @brookyonas

Comment: what are you using for the auth, email/password, phone number or other

Comment: the sign in method enabled in my firebase is the email/password

Comment: check if the password is more than 6 character

Comment: yes, mine is 11 characters

Comment: You can also refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64727665/w-system-ignoring-header-x-firebase-locale-because-its-value-was-null).

Comment: Is it okay if the emulator is using cellular data instead of wifi? @gretal

Comment: I have read that already and im not quite sure why its sill giving me the error

Answer (score 0):

Go to the project folder in the terminal.

run this comands and it will give you SHA-1 for debug and release. you will take that and add in `user and permission` in firebase console in the project. finally rebuild the project again

for Mac: `keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

for Windows: `keytool -list -v -keystore "\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

for Linux: `keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

Comment: I will only use the Windows key tool right? since i using windows

Comment: yes. in your case, use windows

Comment: ERROR: Windows : The term 'Windows' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: I entered the widows keytool... in the terminal but gives me error

Comment: my bad, check the edited command now

Comment: ERROR: The term 'keytool' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211919/errorkeytool-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-p

Comment: I entered it in the terminal and it says:
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: \.android\debug.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: \.android\debug.keystore

Comment: yes you need to Install Java JDK

Comment: Added an SHA1 already but still the error is being displayed.. Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.

Comment: pls help :(((((