# The term 'keytool' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

When I use the command:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\practiceone> keytool -list -v -keystore "\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

I get this error:

`keytool : The term 'keytool' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify       that the path is correct and try again.`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1q2P.png)

I'm not able to get the certificate fingerprint(SHA) on my computer.

Any help?

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/q/6211919/10157127

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem once, here is how to solce it:

**First**, run this in your cmd (command line)

```
flutter doctor -v
```

this will Show information about the installed tooling.

**Second**, in the `Android toolchain`, search for java binary:

```
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
• Platform android-32, build-tools 32.0.0
• ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
• ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java // this one
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)
• All Android licenses accepted.
```

**Third**, copy the path of it until /bin/, in my case I will copy this:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\
```

**Forth**, access that folder, run this command in the cmd (command line)

```
cd C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\
```

**Fifth**, make sure that the `keytool` command is working:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin>keytool
```

it should list the available commands for `keytool`.

**Finally**, run your own keytool command on that path, and it will run normally.

Comment: note, I had to use  ".\keytool" not "keytool" not sure if thats a windows 11 thing or me just doing thing wrong as "Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default"